# No actualizar propiedad en BBDD desde Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, binding

Necesito mostrar en una View (formulario Web) una propieda del Modelo de Datos que viene de una BBDD y que posteriormente al realizar el Submit, la accion del Controlador no realice el Update sobre esos campos en la BBDD pero si con el resto de propiedades del Modelo.

He probado con el `[Bind(Exclude="prop1, pro2")]` y no funciona, me actualiza los valores a NULL.

Yo necesito que no se realice la actualización sobre esos campos en la BBDD ya que un proceso en segundo plano puede llegar a modificar esos valores y entonces se 'machacarian'.

¿Hay una forma de actualizar solo los campos que necesito y no todos?

**EDIT**

Utilizo MVC v5 y EntityFramework v6.

Creo que la solucion seria utilizar el metodo `DbContext.Entry(model).Property(x => x.property).IsModified = false;`.

El problema es que he detectado que estoy utilizando un `DbContext` 'privado', derivado del original de EntityFramework y no esta implementado la utilizacion de ese metodo `Entry` :(

Voy a tener que obviar ese problema y que se actualicen los campos ya que no se puede modificar el `DbContext` 'privado'.

Gracias.

Comment: Que version de Entity estas trabajando si podrias enviar la porcion de codigo seria genial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por favor no utilices los modelos de Entity Framework como el Modelo de MVC.

La razón es que estas dejando la posibilidad a un ataque conocido como Overposting, que es cuando se modifica un request para mandar valores de más campos de lo que permite la interfaz de usuario y termina con la posible modificación de valores no deseados.

Es verdad que uno de las formas es utilizar el atributo `[Bind]` para escoger que campos se quieren excluir pero esta es una solución frágil ya que:

1. Los campos están especificados como `string`. No es fuertemente tipado y es suceptible a errores de tipeo y desincronización si es que se cambian los nombres de las propiedades
2. Se están mezclando responsabilidades entre la "entidad" de Entity Framework cuya responsabilidad es la persistencia, y el modelo de la vista de MVC cuya resposabilidad es transportar información desde y hacia la vista.

Lo mejor recomendación que te puedo dar es crear un *viewmodel* es decir un modelo específico para la vista y que en el controller o en otra clase mas abajo realices la actualziación del modelo de EF.

Ejemplo supersimplificado:

Entidad de EF:

```
public class Empleado
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Sueldo { get; set; } //Este campo no debe ser actualizado
    //... mas campos
}
```

ViewModels:

```
public class EmpleadoViewModel
{
    //Solo los campos que quiero mostrar en la vista
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Sueldo { get; set; } 
}

public class EmpleadoPostViewModel
{
    //Solo los campos que quiero actualizar
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Action Get:

```
public ActionResult GetEmpleado(int id)
{
    var empleado = _db.Empleados.Find(id);

    return View(new EmpleadoViewModel {
        ID = empleado.ID,
        Nombre = empleado.Nombre
    });
}
```

Action Post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveEmpelado(EmpleadoPostViewModel empleadoActualizado)
{
    var empleadoBD = _db.Empleados.Find(empleado.ID);

    empleadoBD.Nombre = empleadoActualizado.Nombre;

   _db.SaveChanges();        

    return RedirectToAction("ActionAlCualRedirigir");
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la informacion, muy util.

Comment: Si te pareció útil puedes indicarlo votando positivamente por las respuestas que consideres útiles

Answer (score 1):

Pero no necesitas ningun atributo de `[Bind()]`, por defecto si la propiedad `name` del control en la view mapea con al propiedad de la clase se asigna directo

```
using(@Html.BeginForm()){

   <input type="text" name="prop1" />
   <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />

}
```

En el controller

```
public class xxController : Controller {

   //otros action

   [HttpPost]
   public ActuonResult Index(xxModel model){

   }
}
```

La clase model

```
public class xxModel
{
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

como veras si el name del textbox coincide con el de la clase model que defines en el action dodne se realiza el submit el binding es directo, no necesitas ninguna atributo

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez deberías utilizar el atributo contario (incluir todas las propiedades que deseas actualizar), por ejemplo:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="prop1, prop2, prop3")] TU_CLASE clase)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(clase).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(clase);
}
```